# Eclipse Java auto complete changes exact matches to substring matches

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I recently got a new computer, and installed Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Since I installed it, auto complete for Java has been showing results in the wrong order. It puts substring matches before exact matches. If, for example, I'm calling the stream() method on a list, I'd type "myList.stream()". The suggestions will show stream() at the bottom of the list, and parallelStream() at the top. Since the default behavior is to replace what you typed with the top result, stream() gets replaced with parallelStream() when I continue typing. The same thing happens on Maps. When I'm trying to use put(), it replaces it with .compute(). On Streams, map() gets replaced with flatMap() as well.

[Example of the suggestions for stream()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Wg3.png)

I've looked all over for a setting to change this, but have yet to even find someone else with this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

If it's useful, I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Took me well over one year to finally hit the 'this is madness' threshold and finally looking for a remedy. If it would be correctly implemented and bringing up the most likely hit, it would have made sense but this way its just a frustration waiting to happen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, I feel silly answering my own question minutes after posting it, but I just figured out how to fix it, so here goes.

Load Preferences, then navigate to Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced. Check the Java Proposals check box.

I'm not that familiar with the different proposal types in these settings, but turning that one on fixed the problem.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting the solution; you just saved me a lot of frustration!

Answer (score 2):

Java->Editor->Content Assist, 
uncheck "show substring matches" in section "Sorting and Filtering"

Comment: Ideally you still see the substring matches, they just aren't first in the list!